# Existing MySQL connection is closed/lost when a new connection is established

Tags: backup, mysql

I have a batch that takes dump (using `mysqldump`) of my DB that is about 250G in size. This dump runs fine till a new connection is established. Now this new connections leads to loss of existing connection that takes the dump of DB. This happens almost consistently excepting some times when this error or loss of connection does not occur. First connection is done using hostname of `localhost` and second one is connected using static IP address of the box.

```
Error log below..
mysqldump: Error 2013: Lost connection to MySQL server during query when dumping table `test_table` at row: 2549201
mysqldump: Got error: 2002: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (111) when trying to connect
mysqldump: Got error: 2002: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2) when trying to connect
mysqldump: Got error: 2002: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2) when trying to connect
```

New connection does a `select * from test_table` (done using `resultSet.setFetchSize(Integer.MIN_VALUE)`) from a table in a streaming fashion. That is the new connection also establishes a long term connection which fetches records one after one. This new query also runs for a long time.

Comment: Well, why're you trying to connect to your DB while dump process is in progress? In normal situation, for integrity safe, you have to use table lock (i.e. default dump mode) - so trying to get something from DB is senseless during that time

Comment: I use `--single-transaction` for this purpose to get the snapshot of my InnoDB tables. Am not worried too much about consistency of DB.

Comment: Then add description of - what error are you getting? What additional circumstances do you have (if any) ?

Comment: I am confident that the new connection is causing close of the existing connection because it gets closed exactly at the time the new connection is opened.

Comment: Is the "new" connection running any queries? If so, what?

Comment: @MarcusAdams Updated the question with more details about new connection.